# pgfplot: Restrict expr to domain based on another column

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have this `latency.csv` file:

```
LATENCY,AMNT,IS_MEDIAN,IS_MEAN
0,0,0,0
1,0,0,0
2,1181,0,0
3,11943,1,1
4,1428,0,0
```

I want to display the median and the mean value in a special color for highlighting purposes. I tried doing this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{latency.csv}\datatable
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{every tick label/.append style={font=\tiny}}
    \centering
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        ylabel near ticks,
        axis line style = thin,
        grid=major, grid style={gray!30},
        legend style={font=\tiny},
        legend columns=-1,
        legend entries={Long plot title, B, C},
        legend style={/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}},
        bar width=.01cm,
        width=\textwidth,
        height=3.5cm,
        xmin = 0,
        xmax = 2000,
        ymin = 0,
        ymax = 350,
        xtick distance = {100},
        ytick distance = {50},
        xlabel={Latency in $\mu$s},
        ylabel = {Amount}],
        \addplot[
          draw=black,
          fill=black
        ] table [
            x={LATENCY},
            y={AMNT},
            restrict expr to domain={y}{3:65535}
          ]{\datatable};
        \addlegendentry{AF-XDP}

        \addplot[
          scatter,
          only marks,
          mark=x,
          color=red,
          scatter/use mapped color={draw=red}
        ] table [
            x={LATENCY},
            y={AMNT},
            restrict expr to domain={y}{1:3}
        ]{\datatable};
        \addlegendentry{Outliers}

        \addplot[
          draw=green,
          fill=green
        ] table [
            x={LATENCY},
            y={AMNT},
            restrict expr to domain={IS_MEDIAN}{1}
          ]{\datatable};
        \addlegendentry{Median}

    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But pgfplot crashed:

```
"message": "Paragraph ended before \\pgfplots@loc@TMPc was complete.\n<to be read again> \n",
```

Drawing the normal ybar graph and the outlier scatter points works fine, but not the selection of the median value.

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

I assume the problem is that `IS_MEDIAN` is not a column that is used for drawing. Don't know how to go around this

Comment: The manual says that you can use `\thisrow` in `restrict expr to domain`, e.g. `\thisrow{IS_MEDIAN}`. Would be nice if you made a complete, minimal example, from `\documentclass{article}` to `\end{document}`, so that anyone trying to help doesn't have to setup the document with package(s), color definitions, etc.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I did add a min. working example (as long as you remove the last `addplot`). I tried `\thisrow` but it didn't work

Comment: The last filter should read `restrict expr to domain={\thisrow{IS_MEDIAN}}{1:1}`

Comment: Thank you @BambOo !

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments